# How to make countdown timer in Python without input?

Tags: python

Iv'e been trying to create a countdown timer for a game in python however i'm not sure how to code it without including the input question for the time at the beginning of the code.

So far the code looks like this

```py
import time
import datetime
 
# Create class that acts as a countdown
def countdown(s):
 
    # Calculate the total number of seconds
    total_seconds = s
 
    # While loop that checks if total_seconds reaches zero
    # If not zero, decrement total time by one second
    while total_seconds > 0:
 
        # Timer represents time left on countdown
        timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = total_seconds)
        
        # Prints the time left on the timer
        print(timer, end="\r")
 
        # Delays the program one second
        time.sleep(1)
 
        # Reduces total time by one second
        total_seconds -= 1
 
    print("You have been caught.")
 
# Inputs for hours, minutes, seconds on timer
s = input("Enter the time in seconds: ")
countdown(int(s))
exit()
```

I want to make the code so it has an automatic countdown for 10 seconds as soon as the user presses enter. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem with importing `datetime`?

Comment: Are you saying your don't want the `input` function to print anything? (It also seems like you're using the word "import" in a way that's very different from how Python developers use it, which makes it seem like you're asking something else.)

Comment: I want to make the code so it doesn't ask the user for the time and just automatically starts counting down. Essentially I just want to ignore the inout question but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you just want the user to press the enter key instead of actually inputing a number? then you can just hard code the time value and call the function with that value, while using an empty input call to wait for a keypress.

```py
input("Press enter to continue...")
countdown(10)
exit()
```

here you're not storing the value from `input` anywhere and just using the `input` function to block until the user presses enter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```py
import time


def countdown(time_sec):
    while time_sec:
        minutes, secs = divmod(time_sec, 60)
        time_format = f'{minutes}:{secs}'
        print(time_format, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        time_sec -= 1

    print("stop")


countdown(5)
```